# Facebook - Get & Display me/og.likes in Video application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Have built an video app that publish user actions towards Facebook.

In this app i have implemented an "Favorite" function that i have hooked up towards a basic open graph action "og.like"

I want to be able to display video's that user liked and apply my own styling to that.

Basically i want to display "**Title**" "**Url**" & "**Image**"

So i use the PHP-SDK towards authored user with active access token and execute

```
$response = $facebook->api(
'me/og.likes',
'GET'
);
// handle the response
```

How do i now sort out my correct fields and display them ?

Am not hardcore at either php or javascript but will be able to sort this out if i just can get a little push in the right direction. Like just showing the raw data

**Update**

Finally a little progress, adding

```
print_r ($response);
```

Will write out the raw data, Now i know that am on the right way.

**Array returned**

```
{
"data": [
{
  "id": "123", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Mathias", 
    "id": "APP_ID"
  }, 
  "start_time": "X", 
  "end_time": "X", 
  "publish_time": "X", 
  "application": {
    "name": "APP_Name", 
    "namespace": "", 
    "id": "321"
  }, 
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "139", 
      "url": "Url to like", 
      "type": "video.tv_show", 
      "title": "title"
    }
  }, 
  "type": "og.likes", 
  "no_feed_story": false, 
  "likes": {
    "count": 0, 
    "can_like": true, 
    "user_likes": false
  }, 
  "comments": {
    "count": 0, 
    "can_comment": true, 
    "comment_order": "chronological"
  }
},
```

And then the next..

From every app "like" i would like to display **Url** ,**Title** & **Image**

From what i understand so far my main problem is that this is nested arrays, Did try with single level arrays and there i did manage to display correct data just by

```
 echo $response[name];
```

So how do i digg in and loop this around, All tips are welcome,

```
{
 "id": "139", 
 "url": "url", 
 "type": "video.tv_show", 
 "title": "titke", 
 "image": [
   {
     "url":     "image_URL", 
     "secure_url":     "image_URL", 
     "type": "image/jpg", 
     "width": 1024, 
     "height": 576
   }
```

Comment: I'm not an expert with Facebook api, but isn't the og.likes used to actually "make" a user like something, and then it returns the like id?

Comment: To 'Create' something is the most common use, But one can also 'Read' , 'Update' & 'Delete' 

'me/og.likes',
'GET'

Will return arrays of all ( in my case ) tv_shows liked within the app. Updated above so see the array there

Comment: use foreach ( $response['data'] as $data ) echo $data['data']['object']['id']; if what you're showing is the true response.

Comment: @ahmad Yes it is, Now it echo all id's. This was huge help. Tested with title and url also and it works great. THX. 

If i now want to display: title,image & url from every object and apply some styling to that. Could you give me a short example so i get on the right path. Anyhow big thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
<?php foreach ( $response['data'] as $data ): ?>
      <?php $Object = $data['data']['object']; ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $Object['url']; ?>"><?php echo $Object['title']; ?></a><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Am very close to gripping this now and i hope this last thing not is over the top.  Clicking on the ID will bring me in to the last part i now added above, From here i need the image url. Is that possible ?

Comment: I did not understand your question, but you can access it like others $Object['image']['url']

Comment: please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078346/display-imageurl-from-graph-api