# Display [Image][url] from Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Building an Facebook Video application. Users can Favorite videos by using in app og.like.

I use

```
$response = $facebook->api(
  'me/og.likes',
  'GET'
```

and i will get

```
"data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "1399918593560042", 
      "url": "http://some_url.com", 
      "type": "video.tv_show", 
      "title": "the_video_title"
    }
```

To get url i use.

```
$response = $facebook->api(
 'me/og.likes?app_id_filter=381977341837631',
 'GET'
);

foreach ( $response['data'] as $data ); 
$Object = $data['data']['object'];
```

Then

```
 <li class="program"><a class="thumbnail" data-transition="slide" href="<?php echo $Object['url']; ?>">
  <img src="IMG_URL"></a></li>
```

The issue is to display the image. If i click the ID in graph API i will get

```
{
  "id": "1399918593560042", 
  "url": "http://some_url.com", 
  "type": "video.tv_show", 
 "title": "the_video_title", 
  "image": [
{
  "url": "https://v.redli.se/p/102/sp/10200/thumbnail/entry_id/0_53lzx39w/width/1024/height/720", 
  "secure_url": "https://v.redli.se/p/102/sp/10200/thumbnail/entry_id/0_53lzx39w/width/1024/height/720", 
  "type": "image/jpg", 
  "width": 1024, 
  "height": 576
}
```

My question is. How do i display the image ?

Comment: It's weird, they called it 'image' then there's 1 object within the array, you may need another foreach to get this like this <?php foreach ( $Object['image'] as $Image ): ?> <a href="<?php echo $Image['url']; ?>">Image</a> <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: @ahmad Have edit my code above to the how it's looking right now. Trying to get the code in that you wrote but seems like i get errors. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the `$Object`, make the `\GET` request to this object-

```
$resp = $facebook->api($Object['id']);
```

Then fetch the image urls from the response-

```
if(isset($resp['image']))
{
   foreach ($resp['image'] as $image) 
   {
       echo $imag_url = $image['url'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you'll need to make a request with the Object id to get the desired image from Facebook Graph.

So, after you assign $Object = $data['data']['object']
You can simply get the JSON from http://graph.facebook.com/$Object['id']
and to get the image.

Example code:

```
$facebookJSON = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $Object['id']);
$myArr = json_decode($facebookJSON, 1);
$myImage = $myArr['image']['url'];
```

$myImage will be the object image url.

Good Luck,
Guy.

Comment: Putting this in will give me "Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"

This is how my code looks now http://goo.gl/AQpVL9, Maybe am very wrong here.